# Is it just 2nd conditional?

Tags: grammar

"I would work on another script later this month, if I thought I could find the time."

As far as I know, both parts of the 2nd conditional are supposed to express present situation. Is it present situation with its present result in this case?

Comment: It's a confusing construction which few native speakers would use anyway. It's inherently ambiguous as to whether the speaker has *already* decided he won't be able to find the time later this month (hypothetical *unreal* situation), or is speculating on what he might do *if* it turns out later that he thinks he will be able to find the time (which could more cumbersomely be expressed as *if I **were to think** I could*).

Comment: Great. Thanks. Do you think it would be also correct to say 'But for my work on previous script I would work on another one'?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps it's my age, but I see it as an everyday construction. *I would go to the seaside, if I thought the sun would shine*. *I would buy a Rolls Royce, if I was rich*. What's wrong with those?

Comment: I reckon nothing is wrong.

Comment: @WS2, gerol2000: The *Rolls Royce* example is straightforward (hypothetical unreal, because I'm *not* rich). With your *sun* example it's not really clear.

Comment: [Relatedl](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316123/2085).

Answer (score -2):

Your sentence is correct, but complicated and a bit confusing at the end with so many doubts, as other posters have pointed out.

Let's forget terminology, and learn some real constructs from real writers:-)

Using tense simplification in the conditional subordinate (see [the fundamental paper by Declerck](https://books.google.ca/books?id=WVqlGOJvcgoC&pg=PA77), Swan, etc):

future --> present

> [Diana Santee #3: Tanderon - Page 114](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Lzxq-_PFAEsC&pg=PA114&dq=%22If%20I%20find%20some%20time%22%20%22I%27ll%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9QMTVeGBIIyxsASUr4HwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22If%20I%20find%20some%20time%22%20%22I%27ll%22&f=false) Sharon Green. 
>   **If I find** some time later, **I'll** come by to console you over your loss."
>
> [New Playwrights: The Best Plays of ... - Page 59](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If%20I%20find%22%20%22I%20would%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22If%20I%20find%20some%20time%22%20%22I%27ll%22&tbm=bks&start=0) 2003.  But **if I
>   find** some time **I'd** **like** **to spend** it with you.

Thus in your case, I'd suggest:

"**I'll work** on another script later this month, **if I find** the time."

"**I'd like to work** on another script later this month, **if I find** the time."

Now, you could use tense simplification also by replacing:

conditional --> past

> [The John Varley Reader](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Wy9eS9th6rUC&pg=PA168&dq=%22if%20I%20had%20the%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1AsTVaO9M5PIsQTrooK4Bw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20I%20had%20the%20time%22&f=false) - Page 168, John Varley - 2004.   **I would
>   inform** him of it **if I had** the time, hoping **he would** not be
>   crazy enough to kill both of us.

"**I'd like to work** on another script later this month, **if I had** the time."

"**I'd like to work** on another script later this month, **if I found** the time."

Comment: There is an inherent difference between your examples and the ones that the OP uses. Yours are not conditionals in quite the same sense as the OP's. *I would like to work (whilst I am there), if I (will) find the time*, is not the same thing as saying *I would like to work if I had the time*.

Comment: I agree. However, I think they apply to the situation.

Comment: There's nothing complicated about the OP's example. The OP's example is saying it is very unlikely he'll find the time. And your last example *"I'd like to work on another script this month, if I found the time"* sounds a little off to me. What do you think it means?

Comment: @Peter Shor: "If I found" is a backshift to past tense representing present time conditional: "If I would find."  See Don't Cry For Me Aberystwyt, Malcolm Pryce - 2010 *'What would happen if I found the photo and took the pin out? Would that help?' 'But how would you find it?'. * You're right, it's not much heard for "to find," but as you can see, it's there.

Comment: BTW, how does one get italics in the "Add Comment" window? Or links?

Comment: Italics: use single asterisks. Bold: use double asterisks. Links: [text](url).

Comment: @Peter Shor: as to the OP being a bit complicated, pls see  FumbleFingers's comment in the above.

Comment: @Peter: I'm probably just repeating myself, but it seems to me OP's example *is* "complicated". I can't categoriically rule in or out either of at least two possible intended meanings... 1.) Speaker definitely *won't* do another script. He would [have], ***if he [currently] thought*** he could find the time, but that's a "counterfactual" scenario, because he already ***doesn't*** think that. 2.) Another script *is* possible, depending on an as-yet-unknown future where he ***might or might not think*** he has time.

Comment: Just an observation. I mentioned from the very beginning that the original sentence is correct. Still, I wanted the OP to learn something new on this occasion: reducing the number of layers. Certainly, one can use the whole sequence of verbs [thought][could][find], but I think that in this day and age some directness, instead of couching, can be of benefit in one's writing. Now, I'm not saying this reflects 100% the original, nor all possible styles, but that was not the target. I was trying to reflect the situation in a simplified way, not the language.

Comment: @PeterShor The speaker is *not* saying that it's unlikely they'll find the time. That may be an inference we might make, but it's not something encoded in their sentence.